# Stata Group Data Into Columns Based on Same ID

Tags: stata

How can I organize my data based on `id` in stata. I have a dataset like the following:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 |
| 3 | 88 |
| 2 | 77 |
| 1 | 66 |
| 1 | 55 |
| 3 | 11 |

I want to put into a single row all the value that belong to the same `id`. So end result should look like this:

| id | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | 66 | 55 |
| 2 | 77 |  |  |
| 3 | 88 | 11 |  |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reshape wide` for this, but you need an existing variable `j`. To maintain the existing order within `id` when creating `j`, you can use an intermediate variable as below:

```
gen i = _n
bysort id (i): gen j=_n
drop i
reshape wide value, i(id) j(j)
```

Output:

```
    id   value1   value2   value3  
     1       99       66       55  
     2       77        .        .  
     3       88       11        .
```